# PrimeNg p-growl component isn't being displayed correctly and won't disappear after delay

Tags: angular, angular5, primeng

I am trying to use the p-growl component for notifications, but somehow the actual notification lacks a close X button and will not disappear after a certain amount of time has passed. To give you a visual impression: heres an error growl:

[image]

As you can see the tekst is shown with large gaps in between the words and the X button is missing. Here is the code of the growl component.

component.html

```
<p-growl [value]="msgs"></p-growl>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { NotificationService } from '../Services/notification.service';
import { Message } from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-notification',
  templateUrl: './notification.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./notification.component.css']
})
export class NotificationComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  msgs: Message[] = [];
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private notificationService: NotificationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscribeToNotifications();
  }

  subscribeToNotifications() {
    this.subscription = this.notificationService.notificationChange
    .subscribe(notification => {
      this.msgs.length = 0;
      this.msgs.push(notification);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

It works with a service, i doubt the problem lies within the service but heres the code of the service.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

type Severities = 'success' | 'info' | 'warn' | 'error';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NotificationService {
  notificationChange: Subject<Object> = new Subject<Object>();

  notify(severity: Severities, summary: string, detail: string) {
    this.notificationChange.next({ severity, summary, detail });
  }
}
```

Can anyone see what is going on? I thought it had something to do with the wrong imports but that doesn't seem to be the case, also I am importing the necessairy css files for the icons so it can't be that.

Thank you

Comment: ok so i've ruled out that the problems are caused by the angular material elements that i also use. Furthermore, it isn't a problem thats specific to one page. I made a growl appear on an entirely different page and there the behavior was also erroneous. On the other page there was no X button either in the growl and the growl would mostly get stuck on the screen while occasionaly also disappearing after a while. Should i uninstall primeFaces and then re-install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok solved it, i forgot to add these lines to my styles in angular-cli.json and to install primeicons.

```
    "styles": [
      "src/styles.css",
      "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
      "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
      "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
```

Also, if you want the growl to dissapear after a while you have to assign a new empty array to the growl message array variable first before pushing like so:

```
  this.msgs = [];
```

If you don't the your not able to push any new messages after pushing the first one.
See this article for more info. https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-4-0-0-rc4-released/